# When to use Camel Wiretap or SEDA?

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel

In my Camel Route I need to send message to a JMS when an Exception hits my `onException` handlers. To speed up the main route, I try to send the messages asynchronously via a [Wiretap](https://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html)

I try to use something like this:

```
onException().handled(true).logHandled(true)
  .wiretap("seda:another_queue").end();
...
from("seda:another_queue?concurrentConsumers=5")
  .to("jms:queue_for_my_exception_messages");
```

Is it necessary to use the [Wiretap](https://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html), or could I go with just the [SEDA](https://camel.apache.org/seda) queues like this:

```
onException().handled(true).logHandled(true)
  .to("seda:another_queue").end();
...
from("seda:another_queue?concurrentConsumers=5")
  .to("jms:queue_for_my_exception_messages");
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use wiretap. Only seda-queues shall work.

[Wiretap](http://www.eaipatterns.com/WireTap.html)  pattern should be used where you want to intercept messages between components for analysis or debugging purpose.

Comment: The EIP page talks about my exact usecase, I want to use the message for monitoring purposes. My question was more on the technical side: Is it necessary to use WireTap to get the message to the 2nd channel with minimal impact on the execution on the primary route? Or is SEDA just as fast?

I think I have to do some more load testing with both variants.

Comment: Yes you should use an alternative channel for minimal impact on primary route. Alternatively, explore the options of using a JMS queue or persisting messages onto filesystem instead of using seda. Since the former shall ensure that messages are persistent.

Answer (score 4):

An important difference between Wiretap and SEDA is that when consuming from polling consumers (e.g. [file](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html) or [ftp](https://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html)) only wiretap is fire-and-forget.

When a thread consuming from a polling consumer reaches a `.to(seda:xx)` it will hand off the exchange and continue the route as expected or consume new exchanges from the endpoint. *The exchange delivered to the seda endpoint will be commited to the originating Consumer by the seda thread and not the original consumer thread*. That means that if you for instance have `delete=true` in your polling consumer endpoint definition, the file will not be deleted before the seda thread has finished.